# vba ms word table row issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

Good Day everyone i got a problem:

I have a form where user can add rows that will be passed to a table in ms word

1. when I cycle through all forms to add rows I call function
2. I insert new row into a table in my MS WORD document (from template)
3. when I try to add text to cells, it adding text to 1st row only!

this is how I do it:

```
Dim frame As Control
For Each frame In fillForm.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Controls
    If TypeOf frame Is msforms.frame Then tablerowadd frame.Controls("krsName").Value, frame.Controls("krsMark").Value
Next frame

Public Function tablerowadd(krsName As String, krsmark As String) As Boolean
  krsRow = krsRow + 1
  With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
     .Rows.Add
     .Cell(krsRow, 1).Range.Text = krsName
     .Cell(krsRow, 2).Range.Text = krsmark 
  End With
End Function
```

krsRow  is a public integer variable.

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?
When I debug, I got `krsRow = 2,3,4` etc..
But `.Cell(krsRow, 2).Range.Text = krsmark` always adds text to 1st row.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's quite easy, you need to refer to last row when inserting text. Therefore change inside part of the function into:

```
 .Cell(.Rows.Count, 1).Range.Text = krsName
 .Cell(.Rows.Count, 2).Range.Text = krsmark
```

as a result you inputs go to last row of the table.
If you change so you won't need to use your `krsRow` variable

Comment: thanks but it didn't helped either. anyway i foud solution, i can post it here if anyone need.

Comment: the idea is to make it through variables as shown in link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838946.aspx

Comment: I think you didn't mentioned in your question which position (beginning, end) of the table you wand to add the row. If you use `.Rows.Add` without parameters than it's added in last row. Therefore my solution works fine. Thanks for the link, could be helpful for others with similar problem of yours...